# System services not available to Activities before onCreate() [KOTLIN]

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have hideKeyboard(view: View) method in util class. In my activity I want to call that method.  I created object in activity utils = Utils() and then  utils.HideKeyboard(binding.authConstraint) but when Im trying to click on constraintLayout it is throwing error  "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" what am I doing wrong ?

my Util Class

```
open class  Utils():Activity(){

     fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

my activity

```
class AuthActivity : ActivityWithDisposableList() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAuthBinding
    private lateinit var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    val utils = Utils()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_auth)

        authViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)

        binding.authViewModel = authViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this



        authViewModel.isKeyboardClosed.observe(this, Observer { isTrue ->
            if (isTrue) {
                utils.hideKeyboard(binding.authConstraint,this)
                binding.usernameInputEditText.clearFocus()
                binding.passwordInputEditText.clearFocus()
            }
        })

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create an instance of an `Activity` subclass yourself. And do not make some arbitrary class extend `Activity`, just because you need a `Context`. Get the `Context` from a parameter to a constructor or function.

With that in mind, replace your `Utils` with:

```kotlin
class Utils {
    fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Here, you are getting the `Context` from the `View` that you are supplying.

Note that you could also go with `object Utils` or have `hideKeyboard()` be an extension function on `View`, if you liked.